# Returning Rvalue Reference to assign to a Lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++, rvalue-reference, lvalue

```
class X{
  public:
  int a;
  int b;
  X(){}
  X(int a,int b=0):a(a),b(b){}
}; 

X&& operator+(const X& a,const X& b){ 
  return move(X((a.a+b.a),(a.b+b.b)));
  //return move(x);
}

int main(){
  X a(2,1);

  X c = 7+a;      //WORKS! WHY???
  X &&c = 7+a     //DOES NOT WORK 

  cout<<c.a<<" "<<c.b<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As I know and also mentioned in the other answers, the returned reference(of any type) should be invalid. But in case of c = 7+a works unexpectedly, while
&&c = 7+a does not work(as expected). Why???

The returned Rvalue Reference in the first case is supposed to passed to the copy constructor of class X and hence the copy to c should fail, right?

Comment: When your code has UB you have no guarantee that you get expected results, but you do **not** get a guarantee that you get unexpected results. "appears to work" is a valid outcome

Comment: Many more users will see the post if you add the C++ tag, and it's also the correct tag. Go ahead and add c++11 as well if you want to. You could remove stack-memory instead.

Comment: @idclev, so this might result in UB in some case for c = 7+a?

Comment: It does not work in both cases, because it is not defined what _work_ means.

Comment: By "works" I mean if the the expected output of "9 1" is printed, and it is working in the first case

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly Expected output for undefined behavior kind of makes no sense. Anyway, you can always study the generated assembly to see what happens at the machine code level. It is the only way how to explain it because C++ by itself does not do that. (I wrote some articles about undefined behavior; you can find them [here](https://yact.tech/en/index.html) if you are interested. I address the issue of "expected behavior" there.)

Comment: All I'm asking is wether the output will always be 9 1 or sometimes junk values?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly Do you understand that exactly what you are asking is not defined? There might be no output at all (this was my case with your code, I got a segmentation fault).

Comment: @Daniel ok, I get it now. Thanks